# Errno::ENOENT at / no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm currently working on a sinatra app and im having a little problem.

i'm trying to load my index.erb but sinatra cannot find the index.erb.

Here is my app.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

module Registration
  class HelloWorldApp < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      erb :index
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my Code hierarchy.

[image]

It keeps on looking in the directory: Sinatra-Intro/app/views/index.erb
but my views is in the: Sinatra-Intro/views/index.erb

Comment: are you running the app from the root or from the app folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your application instance, something like this should work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

module Registration
  class HelloWorldApp < Sinatra::Base
    configure do
      set :public_folder  , File.expand_path('../public', __FILE__)
      set :views          , File.expand_path('../views', __FILE__)
      set :root           , File.dirname(__FILE__)
      set :show_exceptions, development?

      # Optional: Load from external file
      #YAML.load_file('path/to/config.yml').each do |k, v|
      #  set(k.to_sym, v)
      #end
    end

    get '/' do
      erb :index
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

```
bundle exec rackup
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can separate this configuration in a file?

Comment: @JohnGeliberte Yes, you can. I've updated the answer with a simple example although you probably shouldn't be setting some of those configuration values (public folder, views, root etc) from an external source.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default location with the view setting. Like this:

```
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "views") }
```